# How can i read/encode binary file

Tags: binary, decode, encode

How can I encode a file when the text inside is all "gibberish"?
Or maybe understand better what type is the file or how can i read it.

from the command file -i "filename"
I get this result:
**application/octet-stream; charset=binary**

But still, inside the file, I see only "gibberish".

any help with this?

Comment: "binary" just means "not plain text".  Binary can be a ZIP archive, a PNG image, a database file, anything.  There is no "binary" format, there are thousands of different file formats like PNG image vs. JPEG image vs. GIF image vs. MP3 audio file ....

Comment: How can I check what kind of file it is? I think it's a DB but I'm not sure.

Comment: You might get more replies if you tell us more details about what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to decrypt / parse an existing file or create your own file in the format?  What application or website created the file, what application or site uses it?

Comment: This is one of an old files that i found and i'm trying the open it.
What i did for now i changed this file to .bin and did binwalk -b test.bin and i got this:
495413        0x78F35         mcrypt 2.2 encrypted data, algorithm: blowfish-448, mode: CBC, keymode: 8bit

and when i do the command file test.bin i get:
test.bin : MacBinary, comment length 437, Mon Feb 6 06:28:16 2040 INVALID date, modified Thu Jul 19 17.49.31 2040 "\251\305\305\305\305"